# Store multiple day value in single entry in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, reminders, recurring, weekday

i want to store multiple day values like Sunday, Friday etc.. in my database with single entry for recurring alert purpose see my below image

[image]

In this above image i check Sunday, Wednesday, Friday so in my database entry should be single with multiple days and also give me reminder as per selected day so any idea how can achieve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

**MY Query is how can i insert multiple days in single entry in my database which give me recurring alert? Which database structure should i follow which fulfill my requirements?**

Comment: virendrao:but  when i want to update thatdata than how can i make it possible?

Comment: when you update you will get all days again as you want to show whats already there first before allowing user to update. So just updated those all values as a string on previous values. ie similar to delete old update new

Comment: you can serialize object e.g. svc or json

Comment: use comma, when update delete old and insert new list as comma seperated string.

Comment: better you make another table and link your original table by id

Comment: Just an idea: Something like a positional string: `1001010` or `S--W-F-` could make it.

Comment: Sree : Which way i achieve this can you explain in brief?

Comment: virendrao I want alert also for same days in recurring form

Comment: Frank N. Stein: your suggestion is right for insert and update but what about alert? how can i send alert with 1001010 string ?

Comment: I mean you just create another table where you can store all the details of the week and link that table to your current  table by id, so that you can easily select

Comment: Simply loop over the string and find out which are the days to set the alarms on and off.

Answer (score 0):

> As mention by @shree in comments you can create separate tables and
>   link them via foreign key

[image]